# Is it always possible to extend a vector field along a curve where the tangent vector is 0?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $c: I \to M$ be a smooth curve mapping an open interval $I$ into a manifold $M$ and $X: I \to TM$ a smooth vector field along $c$. I know that if $c'(t_0) \neq 0$, then there exists a vector field $Y$ defined on a neighborhood of $c(t_0)$ such that $X(t) = Y(c(t))$ for all $t$ sufficiently close to $t_0$. Does the same claim hold if $c'(t_0) = 0$? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: The relevant term to look up is *sets of positive reach*. If your curve fails to have positive reach, then you won't get a smooth extension of $X$. Try $c(t)$ which smoothly traces out $y=|x|$.